# Using JSDoc to document module exporting class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

The simple class in a CommonJS module has the following JSDoc comments:

```
/** 
 * Class representing a list of items.
 * */
module.exports = class List {  

    /**
     * Create a list.
     */
    constructor(){
        this.items = [];
    }

    /**
     * Add an item to the list.
     * @param {String} item - The name of the eitem.
     * @param {Number} qty - The number of items to add.
     */
    add(item, qty) {
        var data = {item: item, qty: qty};
        this.items.push(data);
    }

    /**
     * Return the list of items.
     * @return {Array.<{item: String, qty: Number}>} An array containing the items.
     */
    getAll(){
        return this.items.map( (element, index) => ({key: index, item: element.item, qty: element.qty}));
    }

    /**
     * Delete a single item.
     * @param {Number} id - The index to be deleted.
     */
    delete(id){
        this.items.splice(id, 1);   
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of items in the list.
     * @return {Number} The number of items.
     */
    count(){
        return this.items.count;
    }

}
```

When I generate the documentation I lose the name of the class. Instead of this being called **List** it gets labelled as **exports**, see the screenshot below. How can I make the tool correctly label the module as **List**?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
/**
 * Class representing a list of items.
 * */
class List {

    /**
     * Create a list.
     */
    constructor(){
        this.items = [];
    }

    /**
     * Add an item to the list.
     * @param {String} item - The name of the eitem.
     * @param {Number} qty - The number of items to add.
     */
    add(item, qty) {
        var data = {item: item, qty: qty};
        this.items.push(data);
    }

    /**
     * Return the list of items.
     * @return {Array.<{item: String, qty: Number}>} An array containing the items.
     */
    getAll(){
        return this.items.map( (element, index) => ({key: index, item: element.item, qty: element.qty}));
    }

    /**
     * Delete a single item.
     * @param {Number} id - The index to be deleted.
     */
    delete(id){
        this.items.splice(id, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of items in the list.
     * @return {Number} The number of items.
     */
    count(){
        return this.items.count;
    }

}

module.exports = {
    List
};
```

it's syntactic sugar for

```
module.exports = {
    'List': List
};
```

It will add the 'List' name, which was missing